# ironpython 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-mvc, python-imaging-library, ironpython

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7OCv.png)recently,i need to watermark the pictures in our databases,we use C# mvc,so i want to use pythons2 PIL lib.honest,itis a bad idea,after my fit my PIL,_imaging ,a question still stop me.
Is it happend to someone?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7OCv.png)

---

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptRuntime runtimeobj = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
         dynamic obj = runtimeobj.UseFile("H:\\vs2015setup_pros\\WebApplication3\\WebApplication3\\bin\\te.py");
        
        Console.WriteLine(obj.f1());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

## pythoncode

```
# -*- coding:utf8 -*-
import sys
sys.path.append(r"H:\vs2015setup_pros\ConsoleApplication2\packages\Lib\site-packages")
sys.path.append(r"H:\vs2015setup_pros\ConsoleApplication2\packages\DynamicLanguageRuntime.1.2.2\lib\Lib")
sys.path.append(r"H:\vs2015setup_pros\ConsoleApplication2\packages\Lib")
#sys.path.append(r"H:\vs2015setup_pros\ConsoleApplication2\packages\DynamicLanguageRuntime.1.2.2\lib\net45\Lib")

#sys.path.append(r"H:\vs2015setup_pros\ConsoleApplication2\packages\DynamicLanguageRuntime.1.2.2\lib\Lib\site-packages\Pillow-6.1.0-py2.7-win32.egg")
#



s="asgrgergerasfefefas"
import time
import random
import math

from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
def f1():
    print s.split("s")
    print "tiememememfff",time.time()
    print random.randint(100,200)
    

    a=Image.open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\11.png",)
    print a.size
    

    print 21313
    newe = Image.new("RGB",(300,200),(100,100,100))  #when the code run to here in C#,it blocked
    print 213131311313
    newe.save(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\0000.png")
    ss = ImageDraw.Image
    drawyy = ImageDraw.Draw(a)
    
    print 768767676
    drawyy.text((0,1),"fewfwefwfw",fill=(0,25,25))
    a.save(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\777.png")
```

Comment: Please add code and explain well what is your problem

Comment: all the code in the picture

Comment: Code should be posted as ***TEXT*** not as images! We like to copy/paste it into our own systems to check out the errors!

Comment: all right,code up,i realize that i should recurrent my operating:open a new consoleAPP in vs, add ironpython in NuGet,now version 2.7.9 ,after it finished
i use my python2.7.10 open a pure python project by virtual env in pycharm,install PIL,copy the lib to consoleAPP s packages ,you can find the path in python code ,if you do like me ,you may will occur a "_imaging" error , i copy a _imaging.py form  C disk ,it solved.
now i am sure that a part of my python code run ,it blocked in "Image.new("RGB",(300,200),(100,100,100))",,thanks alot